# How to control over clustering distance or put some limit to cluster selection?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I have an use case where I have to do clustering on big dataset, around 200k+. I was using KMeans but I'm having a huge problem with KMeans.

Let's say I train a KMeans model and it's ready to predict cluster.

Now, I'm sending an input `

> "(&)=hexvahamje"

It's just a noise text as embedding, and I know for sure that my KMeans training data doesn't have such noise/text. But when I do predict on it, it will predict that noisy text as some cluster x. Which is wrong for our use-case. If there's a text that's too different I want to predict something like cluster None or etc.,

Some control over such noisy text being predicted as cluster x where I don't even have any such similar text in my training data.

What are all the options I have to overcome such a problem? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

By default, k-means doesn't handle noise. It will assume that every data point belongs to a cluster.

Since you need to handle noise my suggestion would be to look at existing algorithms that handle noise, such as [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) which is a density-based clustering algorithm.

You may also be able to convert the problem into a classification problem or run a separate anomaly/outlier detection step depending on your use case, but it is hard to say without more information.